# emberjs call server request twice.. first time is ok, but it refresh for a second wrong

Tags: ember.js, pagination, request

I have a problem with pagination in emberjs... My main issue is that, when I call server for data it respond with correct data, but when it goes to route it call it again...

//so this is a route in queryParams I send "filter", "pageSize" and "page":

```
App.IndexDisplayRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function (params, queryParams) {
    "use strict";
    if (!localStorage.authUser) {
        this.transitionTo('signin');
    } else {
        return this.store.find('user', { fields: queryParams });
    }
}});
```

//here is my controller, with refresh method... filter and pageSize are saved and works, but page isn't...

```
App.IndexDisplayController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
content: ["index", "indexCreate"],
fields: {
    "filter": null,
    "pageSize": 10,
    "page": 0,
    "modelSize": localStorage.modelSize
},
init: function () {
    "use strict";
    this.refreshUsersTable();
},
refreshUsersTable: function () {
    "use strict";
    var that = this,
        pageSize,
        page,
        filter,
        pages,
        i,
        index,
        size,
        $el = $(".pagination");

    pageSize = this.get("fields.pageSize");
    page = this.get("fields.page");
    filter = this.get("fields.filter");
    size = this.get('fields.modelSize');
    pages = Math.ceil(size / pageSize);

    $el.empty();
    $el.prepend('<li><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>');
    for (i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
        index = i + 1;
        $el.append('<li title="' + i + '"><a href="#">' + index + '</a></li>');
        $el.find('li').on('click', function () {
            var thisPage = $(this).attr("title");
            that.set("fields.page", thisPage);
            localStorage.currentPage = thisPage;
            that.refreshUsersTable();
        });
    }
    $el.append('<li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>');

    this.transitionToRoute('index.display', {queryParams: {filter: this.get("fields.filter"), pageSize: this.get("fields.pageSize"), page: this.get('fields.page')}});
}});
```

What is wrong with this code?

---

**UPDATE**

---

Now my controller count for pages and set up array with they values like this:

```
App.IndexDisplayController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
content: ["index", "indexCreate"],
fields: {
    "filter": null,
    "pageSize": 10,
    "page": 0,
    "modelSize": localStorage.modelSize,
    "pages" : []
},
init: function () {
    "use strict";
    //draw pagination for first time
    this.refreshUsersTable();
},
refreshUsersTable: function (selectedPage) {
    "use strict";
    //vars declaration
    var that = this,
        pageSize,
        page,
        filter,
        pages,
        i,
        index,
        size,
        modelPages = [];

    //get values binded from template fields
    pageSize = this.get("fields.pageSize");
    page = selectedPage;
    filter = this.get("fields.filter");
    size = this.get('fields.modelSize');
    pages = Math.ceil(size / pageSize);

    //fill pages array for calc list elements
    for (i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
        index = i + 1;
        modelPages.push(i);
    }
    //set up pages as modelPages
    this.set('fields.pages', modelPages);

    //transition back to route with updated params
    this.transitionToRoute('index.display', {queryParams: {filter: filter, pageSize: pageSize, page: page}});
}});
```

and handlebars template looks like this :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index/display">
<div class="row"><div class="col col-sm-12"><div class="separator"><h5>USERS</h5></div></div></div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">Filter:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        {{input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEntryFilter" placeholder="filter" value=fields.filter }}
    </div>
    <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Page size:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
    {{input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEntryOnPage" placeholder="" value=fields.pageSize }}
    </div>
    <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">Page:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
        <li><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
        {{#each fields.pages}}
            <li {{action 'refreshUsersTable' this}}><a href="#">{{this}}</a></li>
        {{/each}}
        <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <button class="btn btn-sm pull-left" {{action 'refreshUsersTable' this}}>Refresh</button>
    </div>
</div></script>
```

Comment: Ok, so I find out, that I need to use handlebars `each` helper to fill in pagination list... see update version

Answer (score 0):

Send the model instead of the parameters when you transition to skip the model hook.  If your send the parameters it will rehit the model hook.

This looks like an infinite look to be honest, how would that ever bust out of the loop of transitioning back to itself?

Additionally if you override `init` you should call `this._super()` inside of your overridden version so that ember can do it's default implementation of init as well.